# Llamar un método dentro de su misma clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cómo se llamaría a un método que se creo en una clase y se lo desea llamar en otro método de esa misma clase (Soy nuevo en python)

```
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bandera = True


    def menu(self):
        print("\t\t\t\t\t\t**** Menú principal ****\t\t\t\t\t\t")
        print("1.- Crear archivo.")
        print("2.- Escribir archivo.")
        print("3.- Leer archivo.")


        try:
            OpMain = int(input("\n\n Seleccione una opción, por favor (Solo indique el número de la opción): "))
            #os.system("cls")
        except ValueError as e:
            print("\t Valor ingresado no válido. (Solo indique el número de la opción)")



    def llamada(self):
        while(bandera):
            menu()
            Quest=input("Desea continuar (Y/y o N/n): ")
            Quest.lower()
            if(Quest=="y" or Quest=="yes"):
                menu();
            else:
                bandera=False
                print("Gracias por utilizar el programa.")
```

Comment: Cual es escatamente la funcion del codigo que colocaste? La respuesta a tu pregunta es que se llama una función por su nombre y parametros tal y como estas llamando a la funcion menu en tu codigo. Notar que los ; no son necesarios en python .

Comment: Si lo del ; es una costumbre de los otros lenguajes  haha
Pero y si intento llamar a la función menu en la misma clase fuera de un método me bota error

Comment: Que error te tira es importante incluir toda la información posible, como está tu pregunta ahora es muy amplia para resolverse. Editala si es posible incluyendo más detalles.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, el error estaba al llamar la función menu...Python exige utilizar el "self" "self.menu()"

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar un entorno de desarrollo para python que capture ese tipo de errores y te los solucione relativamente facil como pycharm, que es gratuito. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

```
class main():
  bandera = False

  def llamada( self ):
    while( self.bandera ):
      self.menu()
      Quest=input("Desea continuar (Y/y o N/n): ")
      Quest.lower()
      if(Quest=="y" or Quest=="yes"):
        self.menu()
      else:
        self.bandera = False
        print("Gracias por utilizar el programa.")
```

Debes usar la palabra reservada `self` esto accederá a los métodos y propiedades de la clase. También te hice una corrección de `bandera` ya que no estaba declarada

Saludos